# App not found when migrating to appcenter from hockeyapp

Tags: android, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

I have an app that I build on CI using fastlane and I publish on HockeyApp.
I'm already accessing the build on AppCenter and everything is fine.
Now, I want to replace the call to the `hockey` plugin in the fastfile with a call to `appcenter_upload`.

The `appcenter_upload` asks me to define owner_name and app_name.
What I have seen is that these values are then used to build a URI:

https://appcenter.ms/orgs/{owner_name}/apps/{app_name}

When I open the app in AppCenter I can read that parts of the URI.

https://appcenter.ms/orgs/mobile-XXXX/apps/MyApp-Name

I tried to use

> owner_name=mobile-XXXX
>
> app_name=MyApp-Name

This was the code with hockey-app

```
hockey(
  api_token: HOCKEYAPP_TOKEN,
  apk: "path/to/apk",
  notes: notes,
  status: "2",
  notes_type: "1",
  teams: team,
  commit_sha: `git rev-parse HEAD`.strip,
  strategy: "add"
)
```

This is the code with appcenter_upload

```
ENV["APPCENTER_DISTRIBUTE_RELEASE_NOTES_CLIPPING"] = notes
appcenter_upload(
  owner_name: "mobile-XXX",
  app_name: "MyApp-Name,
  api_token: HOCKEYAPP_TOKEN,
  apk: "path/to/apk",
  group: team
)
```

I was expecting this to be enough to publish directly in appcenter but the `appcenter_plugin` tells me that the app can't be found and asks me whether I want to create a new one.
I don't want to create another one.

This is the message I get:

> Error 401: {"message"=>"12345678-abcd-ef01-994a-0123456789ab", "statusCode"=>401, "code"=>"Unauthorized"}
>   App with name MyApp-Name not found, create one? (y/n)

Comment: I guess that the question is: is this even possible? Or do I have to create another app and the one that was automatically created to import the app from hockeyapp, can't be used to directly publish on appcenter?

Comment: Everything works if I create another app and another app token

Comment: got a fix for this issue by any chance?